# I am writing GPS location data to an SD card in an Arduino project. It fails

Tags: arduino, gps, kml

So I am writing GPS data (latitude and longitude) to a SD card in an Arduino project.  I want to write the header for the KML file (which is storing the GPS data).  I have two dataFile.println commands (as shown below).  I can comment out one of the lines and then the other line will be correctly written to my SD card.  But if I have both lines then dataFile will be false (I am assuming it will be null?) and neither line below will write to the SD card.  What am I doing wrong?

```
File dataFile = SD.open(GPS_FILE, FILE_WRITE);

if (dataFile)
{
 if (total == 0)
 {
     //Write header
     dataFile.println("<\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"\?>"); //This line (by itself) will write correctly
     dataFile.println("<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">"); //This line (by itself) will write correctly
  }
```

You can see the project code at this link:  [My project code](https://codebender.cc/sketch:284740)

Comment: The code in the original post was just a part of it.  I do end up closing the file in the code I am using.  You can see the project code at this link:  [My project code](https://codebender.cc/sketch:284740)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 File dataFile = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.println(str);
    dataFile.close();
    Serial.println(str);
  }
```

i dont see you close the file...